# How to save captured image path in sqlite database and retrieve it

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I'm still new to this Android Studio. I've been searching for coding suitable to my current apps. Unfortunately, I cannot find one that I can understand or relate to my apps.

I want to create a camera button that capture an image and the path of the image will be saved inside sqlite database. In the same activity, I want to show the image in form of `ListView`.

Right now I only able to call camera function inside `MainActivity`.

```
public void btnAmbilGambar (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyPhoto.jpg");
    OutputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, OutputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, takePic);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == takePic && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Message.message(this, OutputFileUri.toString());
    }

}
```

The below coding is the method to insert image inside my database.

```
public long insert(Bitmap img ) {

    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("pic",data);

    long a= db.insert("mypic", null, value);

    return a;
}

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

When I run the apps, there are no errors but I don't know how to save the image inside the database. I need coding of how to call the `insert()` method and then how to display the image in form of `ListView`. If someone can show me a sample of coding which can complete my coding will be much appreciated.

Comment: for database storing http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html
for listview http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: thanks for the respond. I already have the database. So how about image path? Is it the same method also?

Comment: my suggestion just put your image id(name) in database and maintain your app path in which you can save all images.